# Javascript string with quotes within ruby rails - disqus

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4

I am setting up disqus within my ruby application and I need to pass some ruby variables to javascript, the problem is that the ruby variables get parsed as strings without quotes, when they need to be wrapped by single quotes for javascript not to confuse them for a string, I can't seem to get single quotes that don't get evaluated as bizarre html characters.

```
var disqus_shortname = 'binaryhustle'; // Required - Replace example with your forum shortname
var disqus_identifier = <%= disqus_id %>;
var disqus_title =  <%=  post.title %>  ;
var disqus_url = <%= request.fullpath.split("?")[0] %>;
```

Im also not sure whether I need to escape the quotes within rails or javascript, im new to this kind of integration and im having some trouble getting my head around it...could someone point me in the right direction?

Thank you kindly

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This should work:

```
var disqus_identifier = '<%= disqus_id -%>';
```

etc.

Comment: so it does, didnt think it would be quite that simple, I take it ruby evaluates `<%=` before anything else

Comment: @Melbourne2991 then please accept my answer. :)
And yes, it does - ruby evaluates its code in erb markup and then push it to client as plain HTML/JS.